# Does the Enterprise Integration Patterns book complements DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design, integration, design-patterns

For those of you familiar with the [EIP book](http://martinfowler.com/books/eip.html). Are those patterns a good complement to DDD? Initially I thought they were more suited to a distributed enterprise application, but I have noticed that some complex projects with just a database as external service, really benefit from messaging patterns.

I have avoided the book since I am not interested in highly distributed server side software. However considering my increasing use of domain events and event sourcing, I am getting the feeling that the patterns from that book are very likely to be reused with any DDD project.

Is the EIP book a must read for DDD practitioners?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say it is not a must read for people who want to do DDD. I'd consider it a highly suggested read for someone who wants to do SOA and messaging.

The Enterprise Integration Patterns book starts out by discussing common options for integrating different applications. Those are File Transfer, a Shared Database, Remote Procedure Call (think Web Services or WCF if you're a C# developer) and messaging.

The authors then make the case that asynchronous messaging is the most pragmatic approach to the fundamental problem of sharing data between distributed applications.

The rest of the book is a catalog of patterns that can be applied to distributed systems using messaging for communication. If you've ever read [Patterns Of Enterprise Application Architecture](http://martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html), it's in the same vein. It's a list of different patterns with explanations of what problem they are trying to solve in a distributed system.

That said - if your distributed systems are using a domain model, or transaction scripts - it's really no different for the purposes of this book.

I just finished reading the book a few days ago actually. It's a great book, if you're interested in the subject matter. I hope this helps.

Comment: I believe my question was not very good because of my short experience with SOA. I've always associated SOA with server/network related software, but with DDD and CQRS I have noticed some very attractive patterns to bind  a local database(or even just a document) with the GUI. I see now SOA as something more than just networking related protocols. @Dan Would you say the book patterns are good even for non network program communications? I mean, the communication between classes based on the notification-observer pattern

Comment: Hmmm... not really. The book really does focus on patterns for distributed systems (i.e. network communications). A few of the patterns could be used in a non-networked setting, but they often already have analogous definitions in the GoF set of patterns. Observer, as you mentioned, is one example.